# Hibernate Check Annotation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, check-constraints

I have a table with three fields, say a, b, c. I would like to add a constraint ensuring that if a is not null, then also b and c are not null. I have done that using following SQL

```
ALTER TABLE sample 
ADD CONSTRAINT no_nulls
CHECK (CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN b IS NOT NULL AND c IS NOT NULL END)
```

Is there a way to achieve same effect using hibernate annotation @Check?

I can't find a helpful example with that annotation, do developers tend not to use it at all?

Comment: Is it perhaps easier to convert "a is null or (b is not null and c is not null)"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible if `@Check` is used at class level like this:

```
@Entity
@Check(constraints = "COL_A IS NULL OR (COL_B IS NOT NULL and COL_C IS NOT NULL)")
public class Sample {

    @Column(name = "COL_A")
    private Long a;

    @Column(name = "COL_B")
    private Long b;

    @Column(name = "COL_C")
    private Long c;

}
```

(Note that I rewrote your condition using @jarlh comment.). The `constraints` clause of `@Check` annotation needs to refer to the `name` attribute of `@Column` (it must be pure SQL).

`@Check` annotation needs to be at class level because of a [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4315).

Comment: Suppose i have: ////////////
@Column(name = "sample")
private Long a; //////////

Which one should I use in check constraint? 'a' or 'sample'? I guess the question is: Is there HQL or SQL used?

Comment: Apparently `@Check` can only be used once, at class level. How can we add multiple constraints?

Comment: Any idea if this is possible, I have multiple named check constraints but no way to add them

Answer (score 0):

Use next annotation at Class level to check all three columns, e.g.:

@Check(constraints = "COL_A >= 15 AND COL_B < 200 AND COL_C > 100")

being COL_A, COL_B and COL_C the column names to be checked

Do not check nullable columns. @NotNull is preferred over @Check.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).