# HIbernate check constraint name through JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Consider the following

```
@Entity
@Table
@Check(constraints = "A IS NOT NULL OR B IS NOT NULL")    
public class Model {

@Id
private Long id;

private A a;

private B b;

}
```

Problem is I do not know how I can name the checkConstraint ?
What I want is something like @Check(constraints = @Constraint("name"="CHK_CONST_1", "A IS NOT NULL OR B IS NOT NULL"))

Comment: Simple constraint? Basic constraint ?

Comment: According to the Hibernate documentation this is not possible.

Comment: did you try this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983454/hibernate-check-annotation

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I too tend to believe so , but thanks for confirming

Answer (score -1):

I think you should used `@Column` and `name` attribute to specify the name of columns.

```
@Entity
@Table
@Check(constraints = "COL_A IS NULL OR COL_B IS NOT NULL")    
public class Model {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "COL_A")
   private A a;

   @Column(name = "COL_B")
   private B b;

}
```

check this :- [Hibernate Check Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983454/hibernate-check-annotation)

Comment: I believe OP is after Constraint name, not column name?

Comment: That is right. My question was to name the check constraint. But thanks for missing @Column for it to work